# Firefox keyboard navigation loses focus on back

Tags: firefox, navigation, accessibility, caret, backspace

I've enabled accessibility.browsewithcaret as well as setting browser.backspace_action to 0. If I use arrow keys to navigate to a link and press "return," the tab loads the link URL. Then, when I use either the backspace key, the alt+left arrow OR click on "Back" with my mouse, the tab navigates to the previous page, as it is supposed to.  However, the page focus is lost and using arrow keys scrolls up or down, depending, while typing runs a search, as if I'd typed ctrl+F first.  This behaviour started suddenly today, without an update. Firefox 94.0.1.

Comment: I attempted to replicate your issue using FF 94.0.1 on Windows, but was unable to reproduce the error you are seeing. Perhaps it might be helpful to uninstall and reinstall the browser?

Answer (score 0):

This hasn't re-occurred. It became fixed with the very next update and continues to work correctly now. It's entirely possible that the original issue was my own fault somehow, although I never did figure out what.

This can be closed; can I close my own issue?